# vmin size changes in Chrome when Android soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, css, html, google-chrome

I'm using `vmin` units in my html5 app for Android. It works just great until keyboard is shown. Viewport adapts to the new dimensions and all my controls with `wmin` size become tiny (almost invisible) as `vmin` is calculated as the percent from the space between the keyboard and top window boundary.

My adaptive meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>
```

Environment: Android 5.0, Chrome for Android.

From the Quirks Mode ([meta viewport](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/)):

> Chrome and Opera give the available height (screen height minus toolbars and such).

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: set user-scaleable to yes for one thing

Comment: @RachelGallen no changes, it behaves exactly the same with `user-scalable=yes`

Comment: I'm also really interested in a creative solution for this as for me this is the only real scenario where I want to go back to other size units. Sad to see there isn't an answer here yet.

Comment: I solved it with @media for ratio and min-height/min-width.